# Implicit keyword

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

```
public static implicit operator byte(BytesType o) { return ConvertTo<byte>(o); }
```

The above does an implicit conversion from object o of type `BytesType` to `byte`.

But what does the following do

```
public static implicit operator byte?(BytesType o) { return ConvertTo<byte>(o); }
```

Particularly the conditional operator. What does the conditional operator signify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a conditional operator - it's just the shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, in the same way as if you were declaring a variable or a parameter. So that's equivalent to:

```
public static implicit operator Nullable<byte>(BytesType o)
{ 
    return ConvertTo<byte>(o);
}
```